# Larger Lady Liberty

Tags: post-apocalypse, construction

One of the great icons of America is Lady Liberty, standing proudly atop Liberty Island in New York Harbor.  Here she is, in all her glory:

[image]

From the ground to the torch, she stands 305'1" tall.  From the base to the torch, she stands 151'1".  Her skin is a series of copper plates as thick as two pennies.

In this alternate New York, Lady Liberty is much, much bigger--from base to torch, she stands 420 feet tall, and her stone-and-concrete platform has to be taller to accommodate that.  Her skin is a series of bronze plates half an inch thick.  And the torch?  It's an actual torch, doubling her into the role of lighthouse.

At these dimensions, how far will anyone see the light from her torch?  And with a larger size and thicker skin made from a more resistant metal, how long would she stand before she falls apart in a Life After People?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is the torch a fire torch or an electric beach type torch? What does "A life after people" entail? You did not provide how you got to that scenario. Was it globalized typhoons? Solar flares? Sun expanding into a red giant? M.A.D resulting in Nuclear fallout? All of these things can drastically change how long she remains standing.

Comment: Does Lake Earth New York have category 5 hurricanes?

Comment: @Aify  You've clearly never heard of the show Life After People.

Comment: @JohnWDailey you've made an assumption in your question that everyone **has heard of it**, which is a horrible assumption to make - You need to make things like this clear.

Comment: @JohnWDailey the other posters are correct, you need to explain your scenario beyond a reference to some pre-existing world.  Its impossible for people to answer if they are not familiar with the source you mention in a question.

Comment: This isn't a worldbuilding question, it's a mathematics question.

Comment: You cannot build a world without the science involved, so there is no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *How far will anyone see the light from her torch?*

At 420 feet, [the distance to the horizon is 25 miles](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=distance+to+the+horizon&rawformassumption=%7B%22FS%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%7B%22HorizonDistance%22,+%22d%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22HorizonDistance%22,+%22h%22%7D+-%3E%22420+ft%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22FVarOpt%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%7B%22HorizonDistance%22,+%22r%22%7D%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,+%22%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Formula%22%7D&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D) putting an upper bound on how far away it can be seen. If she's actually supposed to be a functional lighthouse (the real statue is not), they'd install [lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens) which can be seen that far.

> *How long would she stand before she falls apart in a Life After People?*

[Life After People gives Burj Khalifa 250 years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkAMJepZQH0) and the [Petronas Towers 500 years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8aLKHShv9o#t=2m40s). These are modern and uniquely constructed buildings and only give us an upper bound. A bronze and iron 19th century colossus will not last as long.

The statue will not be destroyed by natural disaster. Standing on its own little island, the statue is safe from fire that might engulf the rest of the city, and the torch will quickly run out of fuel. New York is seismically inactive, there having been no major earthquakes. And the existing statue has stood up to 130 years of storms.

The existing tower, made of iron and copper with late 19th century building techniques, needed an overhaul after 50 years to deal with leaks, and a [major one after 100 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation-restoration_of_the_Statue_of_Liberty). That was with regular maintenance, but it gives us a good upper bound.

Without maintenance, corrosion from water and salt spray will be its downfall. The arm, the most mechanically perilous part of the statue, will go first. Unpatched leaks will corrode the iron and copper. The original insulation was found to be worse than ineffective, acting like a sponge to hold seawater against the metals. It could take anywhere from 10 to 100 years. Once the arm falls the interior will be exposed and the structure will degrade quickly.